# A USB SD card reader on your own PCB

Tags: pcb, usb, sd

I'm actively looking for a solution about this since nearly 2 months: I need to build a USB SD card reader slot for my project [www.samplerbox.org](https://www.samplerbox.org/).

I tried various solutions:

- buy some cheap USB SD reader on ebay and dismantle them : I tried at least with 3 of them : unfortunately, the chip is always under a black glue (epoxy?) and it's impossible to see which chip is used.

Moreover I don't see how I could attach [an existing SD reader](https://web.archive.org/web/20150406200727/http://www.memorybits.co.uk/blogbits/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Integral-USB-2.0-Single-Slot-SD-SDHC-Card-Reader.jpg) to my own PCB

- Use a ready-to-use SD module (SPI interface) like this one:

[image]

But as discussed in another topic, *this works with SPI*, and thus, this is not suited for my case, because transfer rate would be far too slow with SPI (~ 1 MB/sec)

So none of these solutions have worked.

**How would you provide a SD card slot to your device, on you own PCB, with high transfer rate (thus using USB instead of SPI)?**

Comment: The SD card can be used in 2 different ways. SPI or some kind of SPI with 4 data lanes (faster). What device is going to request the data from the SD card?

Comment: @Botnic a RaspPi 2. I really need transfer rate as fast as USB (because loading of 300 MB files in memory should be done in 10 or 20 seconds)

Comment: If you build a PCB on your own, you can also use a FT220X or similar (USB to SD bridge). (Have a look at the Developmentkit)

Comment: @Botnic in the specs of FT220X, I find `USB to serial port interface chips with speeds up to 3.4Mbit/s` => too slow compared to a standard USB SD reader

Comment: SD cards *always* use SPI. The only reason to use a separate SPI-to-USB bridge would be if the Pi's SPI controller is too slow. (However, the Pi's USB isn't too fast either.)

Comment: Are you sure that SD cards *always* use SPI? I didn't know. Do you have a reference for that? Pi's USB can achieve 10MB/s. I would like to have at least 10MB/s with an external SD reader

Comment: Interfacing a RP fast is a hard task ;-) I have given up on this.... (but I have never used the version 2)

Comment: [This post](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/699/what-spi-frequencies-does-raspberry-pi-support) on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com gives ranges on how fast the SPI on an rPi can be (250Mhz max from what I could see). Perhaps that will help you determine how fast you could read from your SD card reader board after you tweak the divider as mention in that article?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong: [SD transfer modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Transfer_modes). All SD cards must support SPI, but might support a faster four-bit protocol.

Comment: Dedicated ICs are available: http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.digikey.co.uk%2Fproduct-highlights%2Fuk%2Fen%2Fmaxim-max14502-usb-sd%2F3033&ei=rRc2VdLlMdHlat-RgdAM&usg=AFQjCNEYfB8ZZ6qO9SF538m6-1OGHsrn0A&sig2=SzJL4zC5wdxeLcA94JrASw&bvm=bv.91071109,d.d2s

Comment: @Botnic the problem is not the RPi. Any [1$ USB SD reader](http://www.ebay.fr/itm/ALL-In-One-USB2-0-Memory-Card-Reader-for-Micro-SD-MMC-SDHC-TF-M2-MS-/251890741540?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_71&hash=item3aa5dbb124) is quite fast, even on RPi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you have to add a custom chip on your PCB instead of using a ready-made USB card reader? I would just use a small USB module like [RTS5159](http://www.pollin.de/shop/dt/MDE2NzcyOTk-/Computer_und_Zubehoer/Hardware/Laufwerke_Cardreader/8_in_1_USB_2_0_Cardreader_Platine_RTS5159.html) inside your box:
[image]

You can get those for 0.95€ a piece, probably even cheaper if you need a lot of them.

Comment: +10000000. It seems that you have found now what I've been looking for during 2 months... I have done hundreds of searches, on ebay, and various online components shops, on some forums, etc. Many many many thanks! I am going to buy this right now.

Comment: I just bought 3 of them. Next episod on http://www.samplerbox.org/blog !